# Iphone 6 Plus lock screen

Tags: iphone

I just got my Iphone 6 plus and there is no option to click on for auto lock.
How do I set my time for auto lock?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the Auto-Lock option by following these steps:

1. Settings
2. Display & Brightness
3. Auto-Lock

Here you'll have the option to change your phone to Auto-Lock from 30 seconds to 5 minutes. You can also choose Never to stop Auto-Lock from happening. If you use Low Power Mode, Auto-Lock will be automatically set to 30 seconds.